# how to load the reactjs dom before the dom of the template js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I integrate the template well in reactjs but when I start the project the dom of the main js is replaced by the dom of reactjs. this prevents the loading of the in mobile mode I tried to add ascyn at the beginning it works well but after that it changes the functioning of the page.

`<script src="assets/js/main.js" async></script>`